# JQuery Ajax uploading a file and other values from client side

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I need to upload a file to the server and send a GUID value, both needed to complete an operation.

Is it possible to send both with one `$.ajax` statement?

Here's a snippet of the Upload action method I'm using

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload()
{
  HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[0];
}
```

and here's a snippet of the Javascript code I'm using to send the file to the server

```
function upload() {
  var formData = new FormData();
  var totalFiles = document.getElementById("FileUpload").files.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < totalFiles; i++) {
    var file = document.getElementById("FileUpload").files[i];

    formData.append("FileUpload", file);
  }

  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/myController/Upload',
    data: formData,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (response) {
      alert('succes!!');
    },
    error: function (error) {
      alert("errror");
    }
  });
}
```

This code is working well. The file is uploaded as expected but now I need to send a `GUID` to the same controller (Upload) so I wonder if I can send the GUID with the file in the same `$.ajax` statement?

Comment: `formData.append('myGuid', '[GUID value here..]');`

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34603739/jquery-ajax-form-submit-that-contains-files/34604232#34604232

Comment: Yes, you can send the strings with the files in the formData, as shown by Rory above, all you need to do is append the data

Comment: Thank you guys for your quick answers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
function upload() {
  var formData = new FormData();
  var totalFiles = document.getElementById("FileUpload").files.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < totalFiles; i++) {
    var file = document.getElementById("FileUpload").files[i];

    formData.append("FileUpload", file);
formData.append("guid", theGuid);
  }

  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/myController/Upload',
    data: formData,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (response) {
      alert('succes!!');
    },
    error: function (error) {
      alert("errror");
    }
  });
}
```

on server side:

```
Request.Form["guid"];
Request.Files["FileUpload"];
```

Comment: how do I manage the data sent in the Upload controller? When I check the values of Request.Files in the controller there's only one value "FileUpload" how can I access to the "guid" value appened to the formData?

Comment: @vcRobe I edited my code, have a look at it

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. It works!

Comment: one of the best and very clear answer, also run on MVC Core 2.2