# ASP.Net MVC Ajax file upload solution

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I know that we cannot submit files via AJAX in ASP.Net MVC.

I'm trying to achieve something like this using Bootstrap modal popup and jquery with ASP.Net MVC. any good solution for this? isn't this issue sorted yet?

Much appreciate the help.

Comment: use this: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload for client side and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680629/mvc-4-razor-file-upload/15680783#15680783 for server side

Comment: If you don't mind using third party frameworks, you can look at [Backload Framework](https://github.com/blackcity/Backload). It might be what you need

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34603739/jquery-ajax-form-submit-that-contains-files/34604232#34604232

Comment: You can use ajax (with `FormData`) - refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293637/how-to-append-whole-set-of-model-to-formdata-and-obtain-it-in-mvc/29293681#29293681)